# Button width not changing during animation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm trying to implement a button animation when on clicked it shrinks and shows the circular progress indicator (while loading) then expands and shows the result of the executed operation (in this case it is login).

The code idea came from this [link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/make-progress-button-in-flutter-d4e2d27bd1d7). The design idea came from this [link](https://dribbble.com/shots/6363045-Daily-UI-Challenge-054-Confirmation). Now I implemented this before and it worked exactly as it was supposed to. However when implementing it again here, on button pressed -> the person logs in successfully and the button changes color as per design an all. The only problem is that the button animation does not happen. I tried printing the values of the `_loginButtonWidth` and can actually see it decreasing and increasing as per design, but visually the width stays the same.

Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:garuda_academy_app/Login/Authentication.dart';
import 'package:garuda_academy_app/Tools/FixedColors.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage({this.auth, this.onLoggedIn});

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();

  final BaseAuth auth;
  final VoidCallback onLoggedIn;
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  // for device type
  bool _isIos;

  // text form field
  String _userEmail = "";
  String _userPassword = "";
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // for login button
  int _loginButtonState = 0;
  double _loginButtonWidth = double.maxFinite;
  Color _loginButtonColor = primaryColor;
  Color _loginButtonOutlineColor = primaryColor;
  Color _loginButtonTextColor = secondaryColor;
  GlobalKey _loginButtonKey = GlobalKey();
  Animation _loginButtonAnimation;
  AnimationController _loginButtonController;

  Widget _loginButton() {
    if (_loginButtonState == 0) {
      return Text(
        "Log In",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: _loginButtonTextColor,
          fontSize: 20,
        ),
      );
    } else if (_loginButtonState == 1) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator(
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(secondaryColor),
      );
    } else if (_loginButtonState == 2) {
      return Icon(
        Icons.check,
        color: _loginButtonTextColor,
      );
    } else if (_loginButtonState == 3) {
      return Icon(
        Icons.close,
        color: _loginButtonTextColor,
      );
    } else if (_loginButtonState == 4) {
      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.check,
            color: _loginButtonTextColor,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.check,
            color: transparent,
          ),
          Text(
            "Successful",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: _loginButtonTextColor,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else if (_loginButtonState == 5) {
      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.close,
            color: _loginButtonTextColor,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.close,
            color: transparent,
          ),
          Text(
            "Unsuccessful",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: _loginButtonTextColor,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }

  bool _validateLoginAndSave() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  _animateLoginButton() async {
    String userId = "";
    String errorMsg = "";
    setState(() {
      _loginButtonState = 1;
    });
    // animation
    double initialWidth = _loginButtonKey.currentContext.size.width;
    _loginButtonController =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), vsync: this)
          ..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) async {
            if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
              // firebase signin
              try {
                userId = await widget.auth.signIn(_userEmail, _userPassword);
              } catch (e) {
                setState(() {
                  errorMsg = _isIos ? e.details : e.message;
                  print(errorMsg);
                });
              }

              // loading timer
              Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                // set login state
                _loginButtonState =
                    (userId.length > 0 && userId != null) ? 2 : 3;
                // change colors
                if (_loginButtonState == 2) {
                  _loginButtonColor = secondaryColor;
                  _loginButtonOutlineColor = successfulColor;
                  _loginButtonTextColor = successfulColor;
                } else if (_loginButtonState == 3) {
                  _loginButtonColor = secondaryColor;
                  _loginButtonOutlineColor = unsuccessfulColor;
                  _loginButtonTextColor = unsuccessfulColor;
                }
                _loginButtonController.reverse();
              });
            } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
              if (_loginButtonState == 2) {
                _loginButtonState = 4;
              } else if (_loginButtonState == 3) {
                _loginButtonState = 5;
              }
              // minimal time before it is done
              Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                setState(() {
                  if (_loginButtonState == 4) widget.onLoggedIn();
                  // reset state
                  _loginButtonState = 0;

                  // reset colors
                  _loginButtonColor = primaryColor;
                  _loginButtonOutlineColor = primaryColor;
                  _loginButtonTextColor = secondaryColor;
                });
              });
            }
          });

    _loginButtonAnimation =
        Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_loginButtonController)
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {
              _loginButtonWidth = initialWidth -
                  ((initialWidth - 80.0) * _loginButtonAnimation.value);
            });
            print("initial: " + initialWidth.toString());
            print("current: " + _loginButtonWidth.toString());
          });

    _loginButtonController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _isIos = Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Theme(
            data: ThemeData(primaryColor: primaryColor),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
                    child: Text(
                      "Log in to continue",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: primaryColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, left: 40, right: 40),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Email Address",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      validator: (value) =>
                          value.isEmpty ? "Email cannot be empty" : null,
                      onSaved: (value) => _userEmail = value,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, left: 40, right: 40),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      obscureText: true,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Password",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      validator: (value) =>
                          value.isEmpty ? "Password cannot be empty" : null,
                      onSaved: (value) => _userPassword = value,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, left: 40, right: 40),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60,
                      width: _loginButtonWidth,
                      child: PhysicalModel(
                        color: transparent,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          elevation: 8.0,
                          color: _loginButtonColor,
                          key: _loginButtonKey,
                          shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: _loginButtonOutlineColor,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          child: _loginButton(),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (_loginButtonState == 0 &&
                                  _validateLoginAndSave()) {
                                _animateLoginButton();
                              }
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Button width stays the same when it is supposed to shrink:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy fix, add a `Center` or `Align` widget as a parent of your `Container` button.

```
 Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, left: 40, right: 40),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 60,
                        width: _loginButtonWidth,
```

To get more info check [Layout Behavior](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html)

Comment: yes this should work too, I actually just had to remove ```CrossAxisAlignment.Stretch```